# Using Google Calendar with Freeboard

Tags: google-calendar-api, freeboard

I am currently in the process of trying to set up a freeboard and I was wondering if there were any plugins for better calendar integration.
MRD

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't any calendar plugin available to be downloaded and integrated to Freeboard. Since it doesn't work using database, you won't be able to connect the Freeboard to such applications.

They recommend you to develop your own plugin and widget, by following this quick and easy [tutorial](http://freeboard.github.io/freeboard/docs/plugin_example.html). I would recommend you to give it a look and maybe try it, since for now, unfortunately, there isn't such type of plugin available for integration.

Hope this clarifies!